# XML parsing: line 4, character 19, text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Hi I have used this below code and passed XML parameter to sql server from C# am getting the below error" XML parsing: line 4, character 19, text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <int>1</int>
 </ArrayOfInt>
```

and here is my C# code:

```
 private void searchLeval1Language()
{

    List<int> ClientId = new List<int>();
    List<int> FieldId = new List<int>();
    List<int> StatusId = new List<int>();
    string[] Client = null;
    Client = hdnClientID.Value.Split(',');
    if (Client != null)
    {

        foreach (string s in Client)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
                ClientId.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
            }
        }
    }
    string[] Field = null;
    Field = hdnFieldID.Value.Split(',');
    if (Field != null)
    {
        foreach (string s in Field)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
                FieldId.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
            }
        }
    }
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<int>));
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    xs.Serialize(ms, ClientId);
    string xmlClientid = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    xs.Serialize(ms, FieldId);
    string xmlFieldid = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    xs.Serialize(ms, FieldId);
    string xmlStatusid = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    DataTable dtLangL2 = RetrievalProcedures.GetPartnerProfileIdforDashboardSearchLevel2(hdnL1toL2.Value, xmlClientid, xmlStatusid);
    chLanguageL2.Series["LangSeriesL2"].XValueMember = "FieldName";
    chLanguageL2.Series["LangSeriesL2"].YValueMembers = "cnt";
    chLanguageL2.DataSource = dtLangL2;
    chLanguageL2.DataBind();
}
```

And this is the code to pass parameter to database

```
      public static DataTable GetPartnerProfileIdforDashboardSearchLevel2(System.String language, System.String clientId, System.String statusProId)
    {
        // create parameters
        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[3];
        parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@Language", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "",  DataRowVersion.Current, language);
        parameters[1] = new SqlParameter("@ClientId", SqlDbType.Xml, 2147483647, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "",  DataRowVersion.Current, clientId);
        parameters[2] = new SqlParameter("@StatusProId", SqlDbType.Xml, 2147483647, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "",  DataRowVersion.Current, statusProId);

        // Call the stored proc.
        DataTable toReturn = new DataTable("GetPartnerProfileIdforDashboardSearchLevel2");
        bool hasSucceeded = DbUtils.CallRetrievalStoredProcedure("[JobApplicationModule].[dbo].[sp_GetPartnerProfileIdforDashboardSearchLevel2]", parameters, toReturn, null);

        return toReturn;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't included the code...

Comment: Side note: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
xs.Serialize(ms, ClientId);
string xmlClientid = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
xs.Serialize(ms, FieldId);
string xmlFieldid = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
xs.Serialize(ms, FieldId);
string xmlStatusid = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

The first call to `Serialize` writes an entire XML document to the `MemoryStream`. The second call also writes a complete XML document to the same stream - but it puts it after the first one. So the second call to `ToArray` retrieves an array of bytes the consists of *two* complete XML documents, one after the other.

If you have to reuse the same stream, consider calling [`SetLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.setlength.aspx) on it to truncate the existing contents between uses:

```
xs.Serialize(ms, ClientId);
string xmlClientid = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
ms.SetLength(0);
xs.Serialize(ms, FieldId);
string xmlFieldid = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
ms.SetLength(0);
xs.Serialize(ms, FieldId);
string xmlStatusid = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```